# Nativescript Live Preview HTTP POST Response Not Loading

Tags: angular, nativescript, httpclient, nativescript-angular

I have created a service to call my API

```
retrievePetData(){
    let body = JSON.stringify({type: "Dog"});
    return this.http.post(this.endpoint, body);
}
```

And I have a component that tries to get the response

```
this._petService.retrievePetData().subscribe(res => {
    if(res){
        console.log("Hello there")
        console.log("Yo", res)        
    }

 })
```

The first console log appears, but the second does not. I've printed out typeof(res) which was Object, but I cannot get the actual value. There must be a response object there, but I don't know why the object is not getting printed

This line:

```
console.log(this._petService.retrievePetData())
```

returns as expected (hasn't been subscribed to):

```
{
  "_isScalar": false,
  "source": {
    "_isScalar": false,
    "source": {
      "_isScalar": false,
      "source": {
        "_isScalar": false
      },
      "operator": {
        "concurrent": 1
      }
    },
    "operator": {}
  },
  "operator": {}
}
```

I am using angular http client. I have tested my endpoint in postman successfully. It is an https endpoint. Platform is iOS.

Comment: Please add more details: Is your API really returning any JSON data? Did you cross verify with any rest client like POSTMAN? Is it http or https? If it's http, then did you setup clear text traffic on your app? Which platform & OS version you are testing this with?

Answer (score 0):

Your service method don't return any data,you should update your method like that

```
retrievePetData(): Observable<any>{
    let body = JSON.stringify({type: "Dog"});
    return this.http.post<any>(this.endpoint, body);
}
```

so, your method should return api data

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Please see new post updates. I don't believe your recommendation is doing anything different than what I have.